# Maximize the Revenue?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea where to start on this question, and I really need help.

A large hotel finds that it can rent $100$ rooms when it charges $\$80$ per room. For each $\$1$ increase in room cost it rents one room less. (Likewise, for each $\$1$ decrease in room cost it rents one room more.) What price should it charge in order to maximize the revenue?

Comment: You know you can get $8,000. Can you do better?

Comment: If you have x rooms going for y each and you increase the price by one, you can think of it as adding x in revenue but then subtracting (y+1).  as long as x is greater than y+1, increasing the price will be effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $n$ be the number of one-dollar increases in the room rate. Then the room rate is $$80+n$$ and the number of rooms rented is $$100-n.$$

You should be able to find the value of $n$ that maximizes the revenue function $$R(n)=(80+n)(100-n)=8000+20n-n^2.$$ Once the optimal $n$ is determined, the corresponding price is $80+n$.

**Hint 2:** Complete the square to rewrite the revenue function as
$$R(n) = 8100-(n-10)^2.
$$

From this, you can see that the revenue is maximized when $n-10$ is zero, because if it is anything other than zero you will be subtracting it from $8100$ to get the revenue, so the revenue will be strictly less than $8100$ if $n-10$ is not zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance, but I actually managed to get that far. It appears however when I try to obtain the optimum price, that I'm having major issues calculating, such as the fact I believe I am getting $10 per room.

Comment: It is correct that $n=10$ maximizes the revenue, but don't forget what $n$ is. It isn't the room rate, it's the number of one-dollar increases from the original room rate of 80 dollars. So the rate corresponding to $n=10$ would be $80 +10\cdot 1=90$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I literally was drawing a huge blank on this and now it makes sense.

Comment: Note how I phrased things in my answer. I **strongly** recommend that you always write down explicitly in words what the variable stands for, before you start doing the math and writing equations. That way, when you get a solution, you can look back and think "okay, what does this solution mean in the real world?". The math is a model, so you must define its components carefully so you can interpret the results meaningfully. It's worth the second or two it takes to jot it down. That way you don't have to keep juggling it in your head. :)

Comment: @MPW: Great comment.In the hurry to "get on" with the job, this basic step is missed by beginners.

Comment: @Narasimham: I appreciate that. You're right. The real point of doing problems like this absolutely is not to get the answer--it's to practice the technique of formulating the attack on the problem. The problem itself is simplistic, but that's so that you don't waste a lot of time on the actual computation. That's almost always overlooked by students *and* many teachers, I'm sorry to say.

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplying two quantities to compute revenue.

Whatever quantity is reduced in one you are adding to the other, so new revenue is: $$ (80 +x) (100 -x)$$

which when differentiated gives: $$ x =10 $$

So 90$ each for 90 rooms maximizes revenue.